# python-2.7 timeit function crashes

Tags: python, crash, ipython, timeit

For some reason, the Python-2.7 `timeit` function crashes in the following example:

```
a,b = 0,0
timeit a=b                  # ok: 10000000 loops, best of 3: 50.9 ns per loop
timeit if a==a+b: pass      # ok:  1000000 loops, best of 3: 129 ns per loop
timeit a=a+b                # crashes!

Traceback (most recent call last):
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'a' referenced before assignment
```

Apparently, I can assign to `a` (first example), I can compare `a` to `a+b` (2nd example), so why can't I run the 3rd example ?!?! Of course, the statement being timed is, by itself, perfectly sound ...

Comment: how exactly have you used `timeit`?

Comment: This is invalid Python code.

Comment: @Roman This is the exact same code that I used (on the command line)

Comment: No, you didn't. `timeit` is a function, not a statement.

Comment: @Fabian Can you elaborate on _why_ it is invalid? Both `timeit` and `a=a+b` are valid, so why isn't the combination?

Comment: @TimPietzcker `timeit` can be written as a statement in IPython, but it is actually a function.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary: Ah, interesting. He didn't mention anything about IPython, though.

Comment: @RolfBartstra In standard Python, `timeit` is a function of the `timeit` module, as @TimPietzcker stated. Thus it cannot be used as a statement like you did.

Comment: @Tim Thanks, but I'm pretty sure of what I did ... ;-)

Comment: @RolfBartstra so are you using IPython?

Comment: @Fabian I'm using python2.7 2.7.3 under eclipse; at startup, it displays 'PyDev console: using IPython 0.11', so I guess I do ... (I'm relatively new to python, and the difference between Ipython and python is still a mystery to me ...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`timeit` is actually a function but some python interpreters can allow you to use it with a **statement**'s syntax, like `IPython`, But it is actually a function.

So in `a==a+b` it actually considers `a` and `b` as global variable and therefore no Error, as it can fetch the global `a` and `b`.

But in `a=a+b` it considers `a` as local variable and `b` is still global so there it  raises the Error, because as soon as python sees assignment inside a function it considers it as a local variable.

it is equivalent to:

```
In [7]: def func1():
    a==a+b
   ...:     

In [8]: def func():
    a=a+b
   ...:     

In [9]: dis.dis(func1)
  2           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (a)
              3 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (a)
              6 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (b)
              9 BINARY_ADD          
             10 COMPARE_OP               2 (==)
             13 POP_TOP             
             14 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             17 RETURN_VALUE        

In [10]: dis.dis(func)
  2           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (a)   # but there's nothing to load, so Error
              3 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (b)
              6 BINARY_ADD          
              7 STORE_FAST               0 (a)
             10 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             13 RETURN_VALUE        


In [11]: func()     #same error as yours
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnboundLocalError                         Traceback (most recent call last)

UnboundLocalError: local variable 'a' referenced before assignment
```

Comment: Thanks Ashwini, you just taught me some fundamental understanding of functions, statements, and local/global variables ...